# Mount volume if environment variable is defined

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Within my `docker-compose.yml` file I have a service with lines like the following

```
    environment:
      - ENV1=hello
      - ENV2=world
    command: -f ./tmp/config.toml
    volumes:
      - ./config/config_x.toml:/tmp/config.toml
```

I want to make it so that if `ENV1` is defined (i.e. not an empty string), then mount the volume

`- ./config/config_x.toml:/tmp/config.toml`

otherwise, mount the volume

`- ./config/config_y.toml:/tmp/config.toml`

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an env variable which holds the name of the volume you want to mount. For ex:

```
environment:
  - ENV1=myvolume
  - ENV2=world
command: -f ./tmp/config.toml
 volumes:
  - ./${myvolume}/config_x.toml:/tmp/config.toml
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker-compose doesn't have explicit conditional statement(`if`) concepts.
To achieve what you want, you have to define a single property key which the value is different according to your target environment.

Besides, [the interpolation of variable in a docker-compose template](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) is done broadly in two ways :

- set the variables in the caller shell
- use an .env file (while it doesn't work with docker stack deploy).

Using `.env` is not enough for your case because you need to have a file by environment with the expected value for the same property key.
A possible approach would be probably to set variables in the shell.
Either manually : `SRC_VOLUME=config_x.toml docker-compose up` 
and `SRC_VOLUME=config_y.toml docker-compose up` for the second.
Or by defining two files that contain the key=value that you have to write into your shell environment.
For example  :

```
SRC_VOLUME=config_x.toml
```

and that in the second :

```
SRC_VOLUME=config_y.toml
```

In any case you just need to use a placeholder in the docker-compose template :

```
volumes:
      - ./config/${SRC_VOLUME}:/tmp/config.toml
```